# Auto check a checkbox when textbox gets text in it

Tags: c#, checkbox, textbox

I want to call a function when text changes in a textbox. The function simply checks if the textbox contains any text, and if it does it marks a checkbox as checked. I have multiple textboxes and checkboxes to do this in, therefore i want a function that i can call each time i need this to be done

```
    private void autoCheckChkBoxes(CheckBox theChkBox, TextBox theTxtBox)
    {
        if (theTxtBox.Text != "")
        {
            theChkBox.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            theChkBox.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

I have then in the designer wired the function up to the TextChanged event for the checkbox

```
this.txtBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.autoCheckChkBoxes(thecheckbox, txtBox));
```

But this gives me the following error, which i have not seen before:

```
Method name expected
```

Do i miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `TextChanged` event and call your method in a single line like this:

```
textBox1.TextChanged += (s,a) => autoCheckChkBoxes(thecheckbox, textBox1);
textBox2.TextChanged += (s,a) => autoCheckChkBoxes(theNextCheckbox, textBox2);
// etc...
```

Add those lines to your constructor so you only subscribe to the event once for each control.

The parameters `s` and `a` are the "sender" and "eventArgs" parameters you normally see in an event handler method. You could actually cast the "sender" to the correct `TextBox`, but it doesn't save you much here...

```
textBox1.TextChanged += (sndr,args) => autoCheckChkBoxes(thecheckbox, (TextBox)sndr);
textBox2.TextChanged += (sndr,args) => autoCheckChkBoxes(theNextCheckbox, (TextBox)sndr);
```

---

When I said place it in the constructor, I meant the constructor of your `Form`, not inside the `InitializeComponent()` method:

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.TextChanged += (s,a) => autoCheckChkBoxes(thecheckbox, textBox1);
        textBox2.TextChanged += (s,a) => autoCheckChkBoxes(theNextCheckbox, textBox2);
        // etc...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This works great. I dont want to waste your time but just for the sake of knowing, what does the `(s,a) =>` mean?

Comment: Great! Even though this works, my designer gives me an exception with this message:
`The designer cannot process the code at line 463: this.txtBox.TextChanged += (s, a) => autoCheckChkBoxes(theChkBox, txtBox); The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.` It still works though.. Should i just press ignore and continue ?

Comment: Don't place it _inside_ the `InitializeComponent()` method (that tends to get overwritten and you'll lose your changes). Instead, place the above code in your `Form`'s constructor (assuming this is WinForms), immediately after the call to `InitializeComponent()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `autoCheckChkBoxes` method isn't a valid event handler. Event handler signature is

```
void (object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Example:

```
this.txtBox.TextChanged += txtBox_TextChanged;

private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    thecheckbox.Checked = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create EventHandler and in that, call your function

```
this.txtBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Textchanged);


private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       autochecBoxes(thechckbox, txtbox);
}
```

Comment: Not something i like, since i have around 20 places this should happen, which would not look that good

Comment: If so, is it not better to extend `TextBox`, add `CheckBox` as a buddy and override the `text Changed` handler?